# MySql and SQL before update trigger set update of different table/cloumn Can't update table in stored function/trigger

Tags: sql, mysql, triggers

I have a connection table, which is connecting with a n:m relationship 2 tables ( A and C). The connection table (B), is holding some information as well.

A ----- B ------ C

In table A, I have a when_modified column which I always want to keep current if anything is changing. This should include the changes on table B.

So I have a before update trigger on table B with following query

```
UPDATE A SET when_modified = NOW() WHERE id = NEW.id;
```

The problem is, if I now execute an update query (with a join on B) I am getting following error

Can't update table 'A' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

```
Update B vv JOIN A v on vv.id = v.id SET vv.block = 1 WHERE v.status = 'finished'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite the UPDATE statement.

You can't udpate in a trigger, else it could happen. that endless loops

But a simple change will do the same effect

```
CREATE TABLE A (id int, status  varchar(10), when_modified  datetime)
```

```
INSERT INTO A VALUES (1,'finished',now())
```

```
CREATE TABLE B (id int, block int)
```

```
INSERT INTO B VALUES(1,0)
```

```
Update B vv JOIN A  v on vv.id = v.id SET vv.block = 1, v.when_modified = NOW()  WHERE v.status = 'finished'
```

> ```
> Rows matched: 2  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM A
```

| id | status | when_modified |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | finished | 2023-05-15 20:31:15 |

```
SELECT * FROM B
```

| id | block |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Eu64vqp8)

Comment: I see. Even if I update in the trigger of table B the content of table A ? Not sure why this would trigger again an update if it is a different table. I just wanted to make sure on a database level that when_modified will be always current and not the software/application to handel it

Comment: the trigger must be removed, as you can't use it  and it is unenessary